# How to avoid processing HTML outside of the template for Joomla components?

Tags: php, jquery, joomla

I create my own component in Joomla 3.x
I have a functionnal Ajax call like this :

file.js

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  data: 'topo_id=' + idTopo,
  url: 'index.php?option=com_mycomp&task=getMyData&format=json', 
  datatype: "json",
  success: function(res) {
    console.log(res);
    jQuery('#resultDiv').html(res.data);
},
error: function (e) {
  console.log(e);
}})
```

controller.php

```
function getMyData(){
  $mydataSQL = $MyClass->getMyData($param); // 
  $mydataHtml = $this->formatHtml($mydataSQL);  // to replace div content with ajax 
  echo new JResponseJson($mydataHtml); 
}
function formatHtml(MyClassFoo $foo) {
  $html ='<div id="foo">' . $foo->bar . '</div>';
  $html .= '<h1>' . $foo->foo .'</h1>';
  ...... and more html code here
  return $html
}
```

I'd like to use the result ($myData = result PDO::FETCH_CLASS) in a view. ($mydataSQL->name, $mydataSQL->address...) to avoid processing the html in the controller function.

I tryed without success a call like this : ...&format=raw&view=newview.

Comment: there is no variable like `$mydata` getting any valuue in the current function then why are you returning the same variable in `JResponseJson` ? Is it by mistake or what ? Could you please write in more detail what you want to do with returned value ?

Comment: @SudhirSapkal Sorry typo. I updated the question. I wan't to use the json response in a joomla view and not in my controller (function formatHtml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want here is to use a layout.

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Sharing_layouts_across_views_or_extensions_with_JLayout

in your controller

```
private function formatHtml(MyClassFoo $foo) 
{
   $layout      = new JLayoutFile('path.to.layout');
   $data = array('foo' => $foo);

   return $layout->render($data);
}
```

and in layouts/path/to/layout.php (or templates/#current template#/html/layouts/path/to/layout.php)

```
<?php
defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;

$foo = $displayData['foo'];
?>
<div id="foo"><?= $foo->bar ?></div>
  <h1><?= $foo->foo ?></h1>
  <p>and more...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You are rather attentive to Joomla questions on StackOverflow.  I hope you will extend your volunteership to joomla.stackexchange too.  (good help can be hard to find)

Comment: sure, i'll check it out sometimes as well.